# PL/SQL missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql

Hey folks im getting a sql error all the way at the bottom 
right before the execute statement at the end of the code block:

stmt := v_first_sql || stmt || v_order_by_sql || v_last_sql;

any ideas of what Im doing wrong?

thanks

```
FUNCTION search_data
(                      
    p_start_ind     IN NUMBER,
    p_end_ind       IN NUMBER,
    p_cols_sort_by IN char_tab,
    p_sort_orders     IN char_tab,                                                     
    p_sor_number        IN VARCHAR2,
    p_tcn           IN VARCHAR2,
    p_sock             IN NUMBER,
    p_work_id    IN NUMBER,
    p_sap              in NUMBER


)
RETURN bean_list
IS
    stmt                VARCHAR2(4000);
    result              bean_list;
    v_jp_ids            VARCHAR2(50);
    v_first_sql         VARCHAR2(512); 
    v_row_count         NUMBER;               
BEGIN
   v_row_count := p_end_index - p_start_index + 1;

   v_first_sql := 'BEGIN ';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' SELECT item_search( id, mwslin,sor_code, fyear, wyear,';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || '  sock,  tcn, non, nomen,sap';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' row_count )';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' BULK COLLECT INTO :bind_var1';       
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' FROM';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' (';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(' || TO_CHAR(v_row_count) || ') */ ';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' ROWNUM rnum, a.*'; 
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' FROM';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' (';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' SELECT ob.*, COUNT(*) OVER () AS row_count';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' FROM';
   v_first_sql := v_first_sql || ' (';   

        v_order_by_sql := ' ) ob ' || temp_pkg.get_number_by( p_columns_sort_by, p_sort_orders );
          v_last_sql := ' ) a';
   v_last_sql := v_last_sql || ' WHERE rownum <= ' || TO_CHAR(p_end_index);
   v_last_sql := v_last_sql || ' )';
   v_last_sql := v_last_sql || ' WHERE rnum >= ' || TO_CHAR(p_start_index);
   v_last_sql := v_last_sql || ' ORDER BY rnum;';
   v_last_sql := v_last_sql || ' END;';




    stmt := v_first_sql || stmt    
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt USING OUT result;

 RETURN result;

END search_data;
```

Comment: How about just showing the value of your string `stmt`?

Comment: Can you print out or otherwise view the contents of `stmt` right before you try to execute it?  It looks likely that you've just missed closing a paren somewhere.

Comment: hmm..not sure how to output the stmt...I normally write java...the sql guy is out for the week...lol :)

Comment: I'm not an Oracle coder, but can you just comment out the `EXECUTE` statement and change it to `RETURN stmt` at the end?

Comment: Would you mind telling us the exact error message? I wouldn't be surprised if the resulting query was longer than 4000 characters and wouldn't fit into your variable. If not, the error occurs on a different line than you think.

Comment: Package `DBMS_OUTPUT` is your friend at debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses in YOUR code appear to be balanced, so clearly the problem is in the text introduced by

```
temp_pkg.get_order_by( p_columns_sort_by, p_sort_orders )
```

This function must be returning unbalanced parens.

By the way, unless you've gone to great lengths to sanitize the input, this is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.